# Python code to query a public dns server for list of specific websites?

Tags: python, dns

How to look up a public dns server like googles 8.8.8.8 (or similar)
and get list of all websites that ends with ".ac.in"?
then write the first 1000 entries to a file dotacin.txt.

Tried the below but it doesn't work.

```
import dns.resolver

def get_ac_in_websites():
    dns_server = '8.8.8.8'  # Public DNS server (Google DNS)
    query_domain = 'ac.in'

    try:
        resolver = dns.resolver.Resolver()
        resolver.nameservers = [dns_server]
        response = resolver.resolve(query_domain, rdtype='A')
    except dns.exception.DNSException as e:
        print(f"DNS lookup failed: {e}")
        return []

    websites = []

    # Extract domain names from the DNS response
    for data in response:
        domain = data.to_text().strip('.')
        websites.append(domain)

    return [website for website in websites if website.endswith('.ac.in')]


def write_to_file(filename, data):
    with open(filename, 'w') as file:
        for entry in data:
            file.write(entry + '\n')


# Get the list of websites ending with .ac.in
websites = get_ac_in_websites()

# Write the first 1000 entries to dotacin.txt
write_to_file('dotacin.txt', websites[:1000])
```

Comment: You can't do this with a resolver, you have to query an authoritative server for the `ac.in` domain. But most servers restrict use of this operation to their administrators.

Comment: The registrar may provide an API or a downloadable file for this, but you'd probably have to pay for the service.